# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test in R

Tags: r, optimization, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I would like to optimize a physical model using kolmogorov-smirnov test between the experimental data and generated data. The output of `ks.text(x,y)` give me the distance `D` and the `p-value`. Which is the relation between them and which is suitable for my task? namely i should take the model that give me a smaller distance or a smaller p-value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A low `p-value` means that it is likeley that the data is different from the model. So you want a high `p-value` to have a good fitting.

Comment: This is not entirely true. Small p-value (smaller than your threshold 0.01, 0.05)  tells you that the null hypothesis is false while having a big p-value tells that you can't false it (this it's not the same as saying that null hypothesis is true).

Comment: @Daniel: Yes that's right. But I thought at that level the answer is "good enough". Don't you agree?